# Prove Plane Divides Polynomial If Roots Match

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

Given a plane $p(x,y)=ax+by+c$ that isn't just $0$ and a polynomial $q(x,y)$ that isn't just $0$ such that every root of $p$ is a root of $q$, how can we show that $q=mp$ for some polynomial $m(x,y)$?

I was thinking of using division with remainders, writing $q=mp+r$ for some polynomials $m$ and $r$ and then showing that $r=0$. This approach works in the univariate version of this statement, but it doesn't seem like it'll do any good here, since the univariate proof relies on the fact that you can get a constant remainder, but that's not necessarily true in 3D (take $q=x^2$ and $p=x+y$). I don't have any ideas for an alternative proof though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more generally, if $f$ is a polynomial such that $q\left(x, f(x)\right)=0$, then $q(x,y)$ can be factored as $q(x,y)=\left(y-f(x)\right)\cdot m(x,y)$ for some polynomial $m$.

For that, let $q(x,y) = \sum a_{ij}x^iy^j\,$, then using the $a^k-b^k=(a-b)\left(a^{k-1}+\dots\right)$ identity:

$$
\begin{align}
q(x,y) &= q(x,y) - q(x,f(x))
\\ &= \sum a_{ij}x^i\left(y^j - \left(f(x)\right)^j\right)
\\ &= \left(y - f(x)\right) \cdot\sum a_{ij}x^i\left(y^{j-1}+\dots\right)
\\ &= \left(y - f(x)\right) \cdot m(x,y)
\end{align}
$$

The case in the question is $f(x) = - \frac{1}{b}\left(ax+c\right)\,$ where $p(x,y)=0 \iff y = f(x)$ and the factor is $y-f(x) = \frac{1}{b}\left(ax+by+c\right)=\frac{1}{b}p(x,y)$.